# Find $c$ by Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

Consider the function $f(x) = 2 x^3 - 9 x^2 - 24 x+ 2$
on the interval $[ -5 , 10 ]$. Find the average or mean slope of the function on this interval.

Average slope = $81$   *(Is Correct)*

By the Mean Value Theorem, we know there exists at least one $c$ in the open interval $( -5 , 10 )$ such that $f'( c)$ is equal to this mean slope. Find all values of $c$ that work and list them.

$$ 6x^2-18x-57$$

$$ \frac{18\pm\sqrt{(-18)^2-4(6)(-57)}}{12}  $$

$$ \frac{18-\sqrt{1692}}{12} =-1.9278273  $$ $$ \frac{18+\sqrt{1692}}{12} = 4.9278273  $$

Then,

$$ c = -1.9278273, 4.9278273 $$

Correct Answer: $$ c = -2.94409720865779,5.94409720865779 $$

I don't know what method they used to get those numbers, or if my calculation has an error.

Comment: Instead of $-57$ it should be $-24$.

Comment: I double checked. The average slope is added to the end of the derivative. Your solution is wrong.

Comment: I never provided a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$6x^2-18x-24=81$$

$$6x^2-18x-24-81=0 (\text{I believe your mistake is at this step})$$

$$6x^2-18x-105=0$$
Can you solve the following quadratic equation?
$$2x^2-6x-35=0$$

Comment: I was going to quick. Thank you